# Can Lambda Expressions only be used in the same Method they're defined in (Java)?

Tags: java, lambda

I see all those examples where Lambda expressions are defined and used in exactly the next line. So in every example I've seen, the Lambda is defined in the same method as it is used. Is that just due to the examples or is there no actual way those two can be separated?
In other words, is it at all possible to call a Lambda function defined in a different method or even different class?

Comment: If you have *reference* to that lambda - sure. You cannot really do it otherwise. The same way you cannot use an `int` variable defined in another method without that being passed or shared.

Comment: Ever seen code using the Stream API that uses lambdas? Those lambdas are what you are looking for. They are invoked in some class deep down in the Stream API, certainly not the same class as the one where you put the lambda in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type defined by a lambda expression can in theory be used anywhere, so I believe that your question stems from the fact that you've only seen limited examples.

I've worked on several codebases where methods returned implementations of functional interfaces specified by lambda expressions. I can give a simple example:

```java
public class A {
  public static Predicate<String> startsWithA() {
    return input -> input.startsWith("A");
  }
}

public class B {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(A.startsWithA().test("Aardvark"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions can be used to declare a variable. Here is an example where a lambda expression is used to store the predicate for a Stream.filter(). Such approaches can be useful when you actually want to re-use parts. I made the declaration in the same method, but you can as easilly declare it in the class as a private final member variable.

```
private void aaa() {
    Predicate<? super String> theLambdaEx = (a -> a.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).startsWith("a"));
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
    s.stream().filter(theLambdaEx).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```